# Invalid phone number error while importing mobile contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud

we are trying import mobile numbers in to all contacts with mobile import activity.But some of the phone numbers are not imported because of this error:Invalid phone number.
we observed that what ever the date failed in import activity,it is in correct format.
can some one know why it is failed to import though the format is correct.

Comment: Can you provide some (anonymised) examples on the failed phone numbers? They always need to have the country code prepended. E.g. for Denmark, with country code +45, and all numbers having 8 digits, you will need to import them as follows: 4512345678

Comment: Yes please provide some error context.Phone numbers have various validations like country code depending your definitions and also length validations based on country.And what's the data type of field on which your importing mobile no.Is it standard field?

Comment: MobileConnect does a bunch of validation of mobile numbers on import beyond simple checking the format. You'll get rejections due to reasons like the mobile number in question was once valid, but has been disconnected by the carrier. If you've correctly formatted the numbers before import, could this be the reason you're seeing what look like valid numbers being rejected?

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to use [ISO-3306-1 alpha-2 standards](https://www.iso.org/iso-3166-country-codes.html) when importing mobile numbers. This includes the local code and area code. See [how to prepare your Mobile Import](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_prepare_file_for_import.htm&type=5)

> The mobile number must include the numeric locale code and area code.
>   This locale code applies only to the mobile number itself. Any other
>   field containing locale information must conform to ISO-3306-1 alpha-2
>   standards.